# Session ID varies between features/Steps

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, specflow

I have implemented Specflow to reuse some steps across features as in this example - [Specflow,Selenium-Share data between different Step definitions or classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30775692/specflow-selenium-share-data-between-different-step-definitions-or-classes) .But when I try to run one of the steps already ran in previous steps within the same scenario,but with new browser session,throws exception Selenium.WebDriver Exception:Unable to connect to RemoteServer

Exception thrown on Feature step below -
Given I navigate to a Help, Publish,  using the system menu

Also verified the SessionID in this particular step has changed from previous steps, which is the When step - When A specific account is selected.
Have included the constructor for SeleniumContext in all the step class files.

In feature file

```
 Given I navigate to a Help, Publish,  using the system menu
.
.
.
Given I navigate to a Help, Publish,  using the system menu
Given New Browser Launched
And Login is successful with "auto" and "ab"
And Set the service to "abcd"
Given Search a specific account to match "Account"
When A specific account is selected
Given I navigate to a Help, Publish,  using the system menu
```

In Steps

```
public MenuNavigationSteps(SeleniumContext context) {
            _driver = context.WebDriver;
        }

        [Given(@"I navigate to a (.*), (.*), (.*) using the system menu")]
        public void GivenINavigateToAUsingTheSystemMenu(string level1, string level2, string level3) {
            currentMenu = new Menu {
                Level1 = level1,
                Level2 = level2,
                Level3 = level3
            };

            var homePage = new HomePage(_driver);
            homePage.NavigateMenu(level1, level2, level3);
        }
```

Not sure why session id changes in this particular step? Its fine when run in previous step, the navigation has worked fine.Using Specflow + Excel for Menu navigation.Not sure, if that affects,but just as an information.